# C# chat windows+windows mobile app based in mssql

Tags: c#, sql-server, chat

I am thinking of designing an application that works both in windows and windows mobile .I have 2 main in my mind.

First idea is to check every half a minute (in a while(true) thread) a bool variable in my database.If value of bool is true then show the message for the user (which is also in a field in the same table) otherwise do not show anything at all.

The second idea is to base my application in tcp udp protocoll which is more of the "classic" way to do it.

The reason i am choosing the first method is because my company has already a wms based on MSSQL server and i don't want to introduce something rather "new" to them.So what do you guys think?

Comment: Need a flag for too broad opinion based off topic....

Comment: Polling is always bad, especially on mobile. Also choice of database is irrelevant, database should be abstracted behind a REST or Webservice. For mobiles, use Push notifications, for desktop TCP to a chat server (not The Webservice though, it's not for persistent connections). Web Client? Use SignalR for persistent connections via http. Once you got concrete questions, start a new question for ONE issue. Don't mix multiple questions into one

Comment: these sound like genius ideas! you should go on 'dragons den'

Comment: guys.....i do not know....just need an opinion.....nothing more.....

Comment: btw thank you Tseng...I will just go to a hybrid solution where i will check one byte variable every one second using tcp connection and if the first bit for example is one(true) i will show the message taken from a filed of my database.I think that should work fine.(the design will be designed to work in both windows mobile 6 and windows 8 or 7 for example....Messages are not longer than 20 characters each so i guess a char field from my database should work just fine).